# date saving in SQL using vb.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, date

I m using the following code to save the date from a textbox and selecting the date using date picker.

```
 If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(DobTxt.Text)) Then
        SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DBNull.Value
    Else
        Dim DOBDte As date= String.Format("{0:YYYY-MM-dd}", DobTxt.Text.Trim())
        SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DOBDte
    End If
```

Now the code works just fine with dates like ""

but when you go for a date like "10/01/2016" I get this error:

Conversion from string "10/30/2016" to type 'Date' is not valid

could you please help

Comment: I think you should learn about [DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) and `DateTime.TryParseExact`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TryParse` to convert the text value to a date.

```
Dim dateValue As Date
If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DobTxt.Text) Then
    SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DBNull.Value
ElseIf Date.TryParse(DobTxt.Text.Trim(), dateValue) Then
    SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateValue
Else
    ' alert the user that there is invalid input
End If
```

Comment: So anything that doesn't parse as a DateTime is null?  That doesn't exactly help with his current problem, which is a date formatting issue.  In addition, this would hide any date format error.

Comment: Fair enough... I added another condition to alert the user on bad input.  The value does need to be converted to a date at some point.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using jQuery date picker, and your date format is not mm-dd-yy you should configure datepicker to that format:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
```

Comment: How do you know jQuery date picker is being used?

Comment: He said so in his post.

Comment: He said "date picker". I imagine there's hundreds of date pickers out there.

Comment: ok, its a Jquery issue, this format works, 'M/dd/yyyy' other ones gimme the same error