# How to validate/save date in Asp.Net using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, date

This code is meant to save date

```
If(Not string.IsNullOrEmpty(Datetxt.text)) then
Sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@dte",SqlDbType.Date)=datetxt.text.trim()
End If
```

What must I add to the code to do validation too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43264937/2157801),

```
Dim dateValue As Date
If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DobTxt.Text) Then
    SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DBNull.Value
ElseIf Date.TryParse(DobTxt.Text.Trim(), dateValue) Then
    SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateValue
Else
    ' alert the user that there is invalid input
End If
```